# How to control BLE speakers with iOS app programmaticaly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, speaker

I have BLE supported speakers which can get connected with iOS device via BLE. I wanted to get the events of speakers such as volume up/down, play/pause in iOS device programmatically. Can anyone please suggest me whats the logic behind this and how can I proceed to achieve the same. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends of your speaker? What have you tried? It does seem to exist a classic characteristic for it (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics). Maybe there is a documentation, or they are relying on some profile Bluetooth.

Comment: Speakers are supported they can play audio from iOS device, now I just wanted to get the events of speakers

Comment: You can connect to them from your app, or from the device settings?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/HandlingRemoteControlEvents.html

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza Yes I m able to connect from device setting, but not from app

Comment: Then you can't have control over it. If you can't discover it/ connect to it **from your app** there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Any suggestions?